# Select the first parent with or without container

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I select only the first parents ul (here with the class `selectMe`), with or without a `<div>` between the `<nav>` and them ?
I need to do it without any class in the ul.

```
<nav>
    <ul class="selectMe">
        <li><a>Hello</a></li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li><a>World</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="selectMe">
        <li><a>Hello</a></li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li><a>World</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

.

```
<nav>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="selectMe">
            <li><a>Hello</a></li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>World</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="selectMe">
            <li><a>Hello</a></li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>World</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You said `select only the first parents ul (here with the class selectMe)`. Do you mean only the first ul with class selectMe and not the other one below it?

Comment: What OP is asking according to my understanding is, to select all the ul in the example with `.selectme`, even if those elements din't have the class `selectme`. And not those inner ul, within the ul.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using a different selectors for every case, and combining the both?

**Case 1:** Select only the first parents `<ul>` without `<div>`:

```
nav > ul
```

Note that `>` mean the child in the immidiate next level below.

**Case 2:** Select only the first parents `<ul>` with `<div>`:

```
nav > div > ul
```

**Combining both cases:** You can use both of these combined by adding a `,`:

```
nav > ul, nav > div > ul
```

Comment: That's what I thought but I thought it could exist a selector to do it directly

Comment: @Lunic There isnt any such *magical* CSS3 selector as of now.

Comment: Yes, that's why I really like JQuery sometimes, certain features are very convenients and could be implemented in CSS

Answer (score 4):

Without the class you'll need two selectors:

```css
nav > ul,
nav > div > ul {
  ...
}
```

`>` here is the [Child Combinator selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators), which selects the direct children. This means the inner `ul` contained within your top-level `ul` will not get selected.

#### Example 1 (`nav` only)

```css
nav > ul,
nav > div > ul {
  border: 1px dashed #f00;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul class="selectMe">
        <li><a>Hello</a></li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li><a>World</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="selectMe">
        <li><a>Hello</a></li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li><a>World</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

#### Example 2 (`nav` and `div`)

```css
nav > ul,
nav > div > ul {
  border: 1px dashed #f00;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="selectMe">
            <li><a>Hello</a></li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>World</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="selectMe">
            <li><a>Hello</a></li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>World</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

> In fact I have to select all the ul in top level and not ul in ul

This is exactly what this does. In both of the above examples only the outer `ul` element has a border:

[image: Only outer selected]

If both `ul` elements were selected, both would have the border and it would instead look like this:

[image: Both selected]

Comment: Yep sorry, I fixed it. Nop I need to do it without a class in my ul. And I need to select all the ul with the selectme class in the exemple

Comment: @Lunic Ah I see, you're not wanting to select the `:first-child` only. I've removed that. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: In fact I have to select all the ul in top level and not ul in ul.

Comment: @Lunic this doesn't select the inner `ul`. The inner `ul` element doesn't have a border around it. Please look at the code snippet examples.

Comment: I believe I am the first one to answer this.

Comment: @RahulDesai your answer was actually posted almost a minute after mine. But what does that matter?

Comment: @Lunic I've added some pictures to my answer to show that only the outer `ul` is being selected.

Comment: Yep you are both right :) Ok, I thought it could exist a king of magic CSS3 selector, but maybe not after all. Thank you guys

Comment: @JamesDonnelly It was posted almost after a minute than yours but its the same one that you ended up editing yours with. So it matters to me. :)

Comment: @RahulDesai completely irrelevant. If you'd prefer answers not to be edited then you should raise a post on Meta about it. I edited my answer because I initially read the question incorrectly. This isn't a competition.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I am not against editing answers, but I am against duplicate/similar answers since it doesnt add much significance to future readers. But yeah, this isnt a competition.